# Static global Variable in C# has file scope?

Tags: c#, c++

in C++ you can define the scope of a global variable with the static keyword to be at "file scope" Is it the same in C#?

thanks!

Comment: In C++, scope refers to declarations, not the objects declared or defined by them. No matter the context, `int i;` has the same scope as `static int i;`, that's not affected by the keyword `static`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The static keyword: In C++, static can be used both to declare class-level entities and to declare types that are specific to a module. **In C#, static is only used to declare class-level entities.**

Useful link for you,
[C# for C++ Developers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/yyaad03b%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

`C#` does not have a concept of file scope. Something similar can be achieved by `internal` that allows you to restrict the visibility to the declaring assembly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is the file scope but you can define your variable in the `class level` and you can access it inside of your class whenever you want.

```
public class MyClass 
{
   public static object SomeVariable;
   ...
}
```

That is the largest scope for a variable in `C#.`

Answer (score 0):

if you mean to make a class called Varriables and then call it each time like: Varriables.myNewVarriable then all you need to do is make a class called Varriables and then use: public static

```
    public class Varriables
    {
          public static int myNewVarriable = 14;
    }
```

then just call it from another class:

```
    if (Varriables.myNewVarriable == 14)
    {
         Console.Write("True");
    }

    >>>True
```

Answer (score 0):

Static member fields can be only public, internal (visible only in current assembly and declared friend assemblies) or private.

Additionnaly you can considere nested classes (even a public static field of a private nested class isn't accessible outside the outer class).

Another way to protect "Hot" shared members (not directly static, but that can be a member of a static instance) is to define an interface (that may be internal) giving access to this member. Then to implement the interface explicitly (specifying the interface name as dotted prefix of the member name) in the class of your static instance. To access this member the authorized code have to first cast the static instance to the interface.

Generally you have to considere using only internal access. Assuming that code in your current assembly will behave well concerning internal access members or types.

Maybe you can be more explicit on your needs and we can find an optimal solution.